# Install Ubuntu on another HDD

Tags: dual-boot, usb-installation

I have a Windows machine with 360gb HDD. Now I have bought another 599gb HDD and I wish to install Ubuntu on it. I have connected both my HDD in my CPU cabinet.
I have created a bootable pendrive as well. 
After I boot from my removable disk, I get the screen of installation.
I get all my created partitions for both the HDD.
I can see my 500gb space as well, when I am trying to install Ubuntu there, I get this

> no root file system is defined

I am not sure how can I fix this.

Can someone please help me with exact steps in getting this done.

PS: I wish to install Ubuntu in my 500gb HDD. All the file format is of type [image]NTFS.

Please check the image..

And I wish to have the startup boot options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the /dev/sda1 partition and change its filesystem to ext4. *All previous data will be destroyed on this disk (500GB).*

After that you can select where the installer should put the root file system (at /dev/sda1 newly formatted as ext4). You cannot install Ubuntu/Linux to a NTFS partition.

Comment: I got it working. The installation is in progress. I gave 450gb space for ext4 format and other 50gb as swap area.

Comment: @Suraj: you just need approximately as much swap as your RAM has!

Comment: I put 50gb as swap. :(

Comment: If you mind you can fix this with the tool "gparted". First do turn the swap off, resize the partitions as wanted and turn swap on again.